# How to implement class adapter pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is it possible to implement class adapter pattern in Java?

I'm trying to read everything on the internet but still have found an example.

Comment: Have you tried to code anything?

Comment: `you can't extend multiple classes` Simple !

Comment: "I'm trying to read everything on the internet " How much time do you have?

Comment: BrunoReis@ I'm a new in oop, i'm going to try it!! Thanks
RongNK@ Thanks!!
MonadNewb@ I'm really doing my best!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* possible, but pure interfaces must be used instead of abstract classes, since Java does not support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two variations of the Adapter pattern: inheritance-based (a.k.a. class Adapter) and composition-based. The inheritance variation requires the use of multiple inheritance, which doesn't exist in Java and therefore it's impossible to implement. But of course, you can do the composition-based implementation, without any problems.

Comment: There are two types of adapters.  Java code implements the Object Adapter pattern in a bunch of places, but the Class Adapter requires multiple inheritance (or at least something resembling it).

Comment: I'm aware. I updated my answer to reflect this.